# Firestore REST API : Push an object to an array value field

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a field in my firestore database using the REST API but I can't find a way to do it without overwriting the field initial data.

Here is the field **Messages** in my database document example :

```
Messages : [
{ senderId: "id-1", text: "Hi Jack"}
{ senderId: "id-2", text: "Hello"}
]
```

How can I add/push a new object (a mapValue) : `{ senderId: "id-1", text: "How are you"}`to my Messages field without erasing the previous data ?

I tried the patch REST API with updateMask.fieldPaths=Messages but it's overwriting the previous data.

Thanks

Comment: Did you use update method for this ? Actually to give an answer for your question I need to see your database structure.

Comment: Have you get any solutions about this question?

Comment: You should use PATCH method with updateMask.fieldPaths=Messages (also with your Bearer idToken)